# How to retrieve specific data from Access database VB.net?

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to retrieve a specific value from the customer account database which has the selected customer ID. I'm not sure how to do this exactly, this is what I have so far.

I will be selecting the customer ID from a combo box, so how exactly will I declare this in my code with SQL?

```
Dim con As New OleDbConnection 'a new connection for the database is assigned 
        con.ConnectionString = "Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\Users\Hamza\Documents\POS system1.accdb "
        con.Open()


        Dim cmd As OleDbCommand
        Dim dr As OleDbDataReader

        cmd = New OleDbCommand("Select Points from customers WHERE CustID= @CustID", con)  'query used to select all field
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader

        txtdiscount.Text = Convert.ToInt32(dr)

        con.Close()
```

Comment: You are missing adding an OleDbParameter to the OleDbCommand.

Comment: ...also, your current code requires you to `dr.Read()` the reader, or use `ExecuteScalar`.

Comment: The other thing to consider, if you're only returning a single value from the DB, you could consider using ExecuteScaler.  Also note, dr is an object that contains properties for each field returned that you then have to read

Comment: @HardCode Thank you! do you know how I could do that?

Comment: Cant you use dLookup? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dlookup-function-8896cb03-e31f-45d1-86db-bed10dca5937

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix you database code with you user interface code.

Connections and commands should have their `Dispose` methods called so they can release unmanaged resources. `Using...End Using` blocks will handle this for you (and closed the connection). You need to add a parameter for `@ID`.

The use of `ExecuteScalar` is addressed in comments.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ID = CInt(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    Dim Points = GetPointsByID(ID)
    txtdiscount.Text = Points
End Sub

Private Function GetPointsByID(ID As Integer) As String
    Dim pts As String = ""
    Using con As New OleDbConnection("Provider =Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source= C:\Users\Hamza\Documents\POS system1.accdb "),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select Points from customers WHERE CustID= @CustID", con)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CustID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = ID
        con.Open()
        pts = CStr(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
    End Using
    Return pts
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked.