# How to query an ACCESS database to a variable

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

I am trying to query an access database to find in a row exists in the database and if the value of IsManager = True or not. I'm new to using databases so any help is good thanks yall :) <3

```
    Try
        Dim SQL As String
        Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
        Dim DT As New DataTable
        Dim D_A As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
        MainMenu.Con.Open()

        SQL = ("SELECT * FROM Staff WHERE Login = " & ID)
        CMD.Connection = MainMenu.Con
        CMD.CommandText = SQL
        D_A.SelectCommand = CMD

        D_A.Fill(DT)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MainMenu.Con.Close()
    End Try
```

Comment: How hae you tried to do this `IsManager` part?

Comment: @Nathan_Sav i haven't yet because i have no idea how. I thought of trying to do a 'For ID in X' but no clue how if that makes sense?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to retrieve specific data from Access database VB.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69759908/how-to-retrieve-specific-data-from-access-database-vb-net)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't fill a DataTable and then retrieve a field inside it.
Insert in a variable the value you want to get.

```
Dim IsManager as Boolean
Try
    Dim SQL As String
    Dim CMD As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim D_A As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter    

    SQL = ("SELECT IsManager FROM Staff WHERE Login = " & ID)
    CMD.Connection = MainMenu.Con
    CMD.CommandText = SQL
    D_A.SelectCommand = CMD

    MainMenu.Con.Open()

    Dim Dr as OleDbDataReader = CMD.ExecuteReader

    Dr.Read()
    IsManager = Dr.Item("IsManager")
    Dr.Close()

Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
Finally
    MainMenu.Con.Close()
End Try
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I get a red line under 'SQLdatareader' however?

Comment: Connections need to be disposed as well as closed. Try Using blocks for connections, commands and data readers.

Comment: @Ben711Gaming Use OleDbDataReader instead of SqlDataReader (my bad).

Comment: Further improvement might be made by actually including the IsManager filter in the query and just checking for existence. It doesn't matter much on MS Access but it's a good habit to get into for larger databases.